# How do I implement organization chart from highcharts in Angular 8?

Tags: angular

I want to integrate the Organization chart from the Highcharts using Angular 8.

But, when I tried to implement with the following code it throws me an error in **series type**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts';
import HighchartsSankey from "highcharts/modules/sankey";
import HighchartsOrganization from "highcharts/modules/organization";
import HighchartsExporting from "highcharts/modules/exporting";

HighchartsSankey(Highcharts);
HighchartsOrganization(Highcharts);
HighchartsExporting(Highcharts);

@Component({
  selector: 'organization-users',...
})
export class OrganizationComponent implements OnInit {
  ngOnInit() {

    Highcharts.chart({
      chart: {
          height: 600,
          inverted: true
      },

      title: {
          text: 'Highcharts Org Chart'
      },

      series: [{
          **type: 'organization',**
          keys: ['from', 'to'],
          data: [
              ['Shareholders', 'Board'],
              ['Board', 'CEO'],
              ['CEO', 'CTO'],
              ['CEO', 'CPO']
          ],...
```

Comment: It's working fine for me as your code does. I need drag and drop events supposed to be work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rendering an Organization Chart can be tricky.

If there's any additional module that we have to use in there, we have to first register them with Highcharts as they've suggested [**in this article here**](https://www.highcharts.com/blog/post/highcharts-and-angular-7/).

Since we need to use the `organization` module which also depends on `sankey`, we'll first have to register `sankey` and then `organization` with highcharts. That's what the following lines do:

```
declare var require: any;
let sankey = require("highcharts/modules/sankey");
let organization = require("highcharts/modules/organization");

sankey(Highcharts);
organization(Highcharts);
```

Once that's done, rendering the chart is pretty much straight forward.

Here, give this a try:

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from "@angular/core";
import * as Highcharts from "highcharts";

declare var require: any;
let sankey = require("highcharts/modules/sankey");
let organization = require("highcharts/modules/organization");

sankey(Highcharts);
organization(Highcharts);

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChild("orgChartContainer", { static: false }) orgChartContainer;

  ngOnInit() {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    //Organization chart starts
    /* Highcharts.chart(this.barChartContainer.nativeElement, {
      // Created pie chart using Highchart
      chart: {
        type: "column"
      },

      xAxis: {
        type: "category"
      },

      series: [
        {
          name: "TOTAL chart",
          data: [
            {
              name: "Planned",
              y: 30,
              drilldown: "planned"
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      //Drill Downs
      drilldown: {
        series: [
          {
            name: "Planned Drill Down",
            id: "planned",
            data: [["plan A", 55.03], ["plan B", 15.83]]
          }
        ]
      }
    }); */

    Highcharts.chart(this.orgChartContainer.nativeElement, {
      chart: {
        height: 600,
        inverted: true
      },

      title: {
        text: "Highcharts Org Chart"
      },

      accessibility: {
        point: {
          descriptionFormatter: function(point) {
            var nodeName = point.toNode.name,
              nodeId = point.toNode.id,
              nodeDesc =
                nodeName === nodeId ? nodeName : nodeName + ", " + nodeId,
              parentDesc = point.fromNode.id;
            return (
              point.index + ". " + nodeDesc + ", reports to " + parentDesc + "."
            );
          }
        }
      },

      series: [
        {
          type: "organization",
          name: "Highsoft",
          keys: ["from", "to"],
          data: [
            ["Shareholders", "Board"],
            ["Board", "CEO"],
            ["CEO", "CTO"],
            ["CEO", "CPO"],
            ["CEO", "CSO"],
            ["CEO", "CMO"],
            ["CEO", "HR"],
            ["CTO", "Product"],
            ["CTO", "Web"],
            ["CSO", "Sales"],
            ["CMO", "Market"]
          ],
          levels: [
            {
              level: 0,
              color: "silver",
              dataLabels: {
                color: "black"
              },
              height: 25
            },
            {
              level: 1,
              color: "silver",
              dataLabels: {
                color: "black"
              },
              height: 25
            },
            {
              level: 2,
              color: "#980104"
            },
            {
              level: 4,
              color: "#359154"
            }
          ],
          nodes: [
            {
              id: "Shareholders"
            },
            {
              id: "Board"
            },
            {
              id: "CEO",
              title: "CEO",
              name: "Grethe Hjetland",
              image:
                "https://wp-assets.highcharts.com/www-highcharts-com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/12132317/Grethe.jpg"
            },
            {
              id: "HR",
              title: "HR/CFO",
              name: "Anne Jorunn Fjærestad",
              color: "#007ad0",
              image:
                "https://wp-assets.highcharts.com/www-highcharts-com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/12132314/AnneJorunn.jpg",
              column: 3,
              offset: "75%"
            },
            {
              id: "CTO",
              title: "CTO",
              name: "Christer Vasseng",
              column: 4,
              image:
                "https://wp-assets.highcharts.com/www-highcharts-com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/12140620/Christer.jpg",
              layout: "hanging"
            },
            {
              id: "CPO",
              title: "CPO",
              name: "Torstein Hønsi",
              column: 4,
              image:
                "https://wp-assets.highcharts.com/www-highcharts-com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/12131849/Torstein1.jpg"
            },
            {
              id: "CSO",
              title: "CSO",
              name: "Anita Nesse",
              column: 4,
              image:
                "https://wp-assets.highcharts.com/www-highcharts-com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/12132313/Anita.jpg",
              layout: "hanging"
            },
            {
              id: "CMO",
              title: "CMO",
              name: "Vidar Brekke",
              column: 4,
              image:
                "https://wp-assets.highcharts.com/www-highcharts-com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/13105551/Vidar.jpg",
              layout: "hanging"
            },
            {
              id: "Product",
              name: "Product developers"
            },
            {
              id: "Web",
              name: "Web devs, sys admin"
            },
            {
              id: "Sales",
              name: "Sales team"
            },
            {
              id: "Market",
              name: "Marketing team"
            }
          ],
          colorByPoint: false,
          color: "#007ad0",
          dataLabels: {
            color: "white"
          },
          borderColor: "white",
          nodeWidth: 65
        }
      ],
      tooltip: {
        outside: true
      },
      exporting: {
        allowHTML: true,
        sourceWidth: 800,
        sourceHeight: 600
      }
    });

    //Organization chart ends
  }
}
```

And in your template:

```
<div #orgChartContainer></div>
```

---

> Here's a [**Sample Demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-highcharts-example-stackoverflow) for your ref.

Comment: Thanks. Can you add drag and drop events to this?

Comment: I suggest you ask a separate question regarding this to keep this thread focused. :) Do consider trying it out on your own once and share your inputs in the question so that people have an idea of the things you've tried prior to asking.